symbol lookup error and undefined symbol while creating custom controller
I'm new on ros2 and I'm trying to build a custom controller for my Ufactory Lite6.
My controller is named uf_robot_force_controller. When I try to load it I get:
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1732123890.403923051] [controller_manager]: Loading controller 'uf_robot_force_controller'
[ros2_control_node-1] /opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node: symbol lookup error: /home/senyoritingo/COPIA_UFACTORY/ufactory_lite6_ros2_control/dev_ws/install/xarm_controller/lib/xarm_controller/libuf_robot_force_controller.so: undefined symbol: _ZN25uf_robot_force_controller22UFRobotForceControllerC1Ev

I don't know if it's a plugin problem or with the cmake or the controller itself.
My CMake:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(xarm_controller)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic
    -Wno-sign-compare
    -Wno-unused-parameter 
  )
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

find_package(hardware_interface REQUIRED)
find_package(controller_interface REQUIRED)
find_package(pluginlib REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp_action REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp_lifecycle REQUIRED)
find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(controller_manager_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(xarm_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(xarm_api REQUIRED)
find_package(xarm_sdk REQUIRED)

add_library(
  uf_robot_hardware
  SHARED
  src/hardware/uf_robot_system_hardware.cpp
  src/hardware/uf_robot_fake_system_hardware.cpp
)
add_library(
  uf_robot_force_controller
  SHARED
  src/hardware/uf_robot_system_force_controller.cpp
)
target_include_directories(
  uf_robot_hardware
  PRIVATE
  include
  ${xarm_sdk_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${xarm_api_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${ament_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
target_include_directories(
  uf_robot_force_controller
  PRIVATE
  include
  ${xarm_sdk_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${xarm_api_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${ament_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
ament_target_dependencies(
  uf_robot_hardware
  hardware_interface
  controller_interface
  pluginlib
  rclcpp
  rclcpp_action
  rclcpp_lifecycle
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  controller_manager_msgs
  xarm_msgs
)
ament_target_dependencies(
  uf_robot_force_controller
  hardware_interface
  controller_interface
  pluginlib
  rclcpp
  rclcpp_action
  rclcpp_lifecycle
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  controller_manager_msgs
  xarm_msgs
)

# message(STATUS "xarm_sdk_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${xarm_sdk_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
# message(WARNING "xarm_api_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${xarm_api_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
# message(WARNING "xarm_sdk_LIBRARIES: ${xarm_sdk_LIBRARIES}")
# message(WARNING "xarm_api_LIBRARIES: ${xarm_api_LIBRARIES}")

target_link_libraries(uf_robot_hardware 
  ${xarm_api_LIBRARIES}
  ${ament_LIBRARIES}
)

target_link_libraries(uf_robot_force_controller
  ${xarm_api_LIBRARIES}
  ${ament_LIBRARIES}
  ${rclcpp_LIBRARIES}
  ${controller_interface_LIBRARIES}
)

pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(hardware_interface uf_hardware_interface_plugins.xml)
pluginlib_export_plugin_description_file(controller_interface uf_robot_force_controller_plugin.xml)

install(
  DIRECTORY include/
  DESTINATION include
)

install(
  TARGETS uf_robot_hardware
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

install(
  TARGETS uf_robot_force_controller
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

install(DIRECTORY
  launch
  config
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/
)

ament_export_include_directories(include)
ament_export_libraries(uf_robot_hardware uf_robot_force_controller)
ament_export_dependencies(
  hardware_interface
  pluginlib
  rclcpp
)

ament_package()


A minor problem I have it's that if don't declare the type on the launch.py doesn't get it. I would like it to take it from the .yaml but it just doesn't.
Launch File:
import os
import yaml
from ament_index_python import get_package_share_directory
from launch.launch_description_sources import load_python_launch_file_as_module
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import OpaqueFunction
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare


def generate_launch_description():

    pkg_share = get_package_share_directory('xarm_controller')
    yaml_file = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'config', 'lite6_force_controller.yaml')

    load_force_controller = Node(
        package='controller_manager',
        executable='spawner',
        arguments=['uf_robot_force_controller', '--controller-type', 'uf_robot_force_controller/UFRobotForceController'],
        parameters=[yaml_file],
        output='screen'
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        load_force_controller,
    ])
```


I suggest that you start with the ros2_control_demos, e.g. example_7 and compare the controller files with yours.
Choose the right branch according to your distro!

Finally it was a constructor problem with my controller. I just added controller_constructor() = default; and it worked fine. Thank you!
